# why is there a null pointer exception in the for loop, when I can have access the array element?

Tags: java, calendar, temboo

I am using temboo to get all the events for a calendar. However, i am trying to create a hashtable of the events and the days. but the for loop says its a null pointer exception even though the program is actually able to access that ith element. I have even printed it and the i is less than the size of the array. Here is the snippet code: Error is in the second line of the for loop.Errr occurs when i = 23, but items.size is 41.

```
GetAllEvents getAllEventsChoreo = new GetAllEvents(session);

// Get an InputSet object for the choreo
GetAllEventsInputSet getAllEventsInputs = getAllEventsChoreo.newInputSet();

// Set inputs
getAllEventsInputs.set_AccessToken(accessToken);
getAllEventsInputs.set_ClientID(clientID);
getAllEventsInputs.set_ClientSecret(clientSecret);
getAllEventsInputs.set_CalendarID(callIDs[0]);

// Execute Choreo
GetAllEventsResultSet getAllEventsResults =    getAllEventsChoreo.execute(getAllEventsInputs);
results = getAllEventsResults.get_Response();
System.out.println(results);

root = jp.parse(results);
rootobj = root.getAsJsonObject();
JsonArray items = rootobj.get("items").getAsJsonArray();

System.out.println("Abour to enter the for loop\nItems:\n"+items.toString());
System.out.println("****************************\nEnter the for loop");
System.out.println("iems Size: "+items.size());
System.out.println(items.get(23).toString());
for(int i = 0;i < items.size();i++)
{
    System.out.println("i: "+i);
    String startTime = items.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("start").getAsJsonObject().get("dateTime").getAsString();
    System.out.println("startTime: "+startTime);
    String dayKey = startTime.split("T")[0];

    if(dayKey.equals(beginDate)==false | dayKey.equals(endDate)==false)
        {
        System.out.println(startTime + " not the one interested so skipping");
        continue;
        }
    System.out.println("passed the first if in for loop");

    String endTime = items.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("end").getAsJsonObject().get("dateTime").getAsString();
    String name = items.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("summary").getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsString();

    calendarEvent eventTemp = new calendarEvent(name,startTime,endTime);

    if(table.containsKey(dayKey))
        table.get(dayKey).add(eventTemp);
    else
    {   
    ArrayList<calendarEvent> schedule = new ArrayList<calendarEvent>();
    schedule.add(eventTemp);
    table.put(dayKey,schedule);
    }
}
Set<String> key = table.keySet();
Iterator<String> it = key.iterator();



    while(it.hasNext())
    {
        String keyValue = it.next();
        System.out.println("Events on "+keyValue);
        ArrayList<calendarEvent> temp = table.get(keyValue);

        for(int j =0;j<temp.size();j++)
        {
            System.out.println(temp.get(j));
        }
    }
```

After breaking down the exception line, the exception occurs when I try to get the dateTime as string, the last part creates an exception.

Comment: Which line causes the exception?

Comment: Actually, it'd be good to reproduce the *full text* of the error message so someone can figure it out.

Comment: String endTime = items.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("end").getAsJsonObject().get("dateTime").getAsString();

Comment: Line 152 causes an error. Here is the full text of the error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at CheckFreeTime.main(CheckFreeTime.java:152)

Comment: Either items, or any of the other points in the chained call is null. It's not possible to tell from the information provided which, but you could try breaking that line into several statements to find out.

Comment: @Romski's point is excellent.  A big part of debugging is writing code that avoids lengthy `.` chains that make it more difficult.

Comment: Maybe this is a reoccurring event without a specific start dateTime. If you say breaking down revealed that `get("dateTime").getAsString()` causes the error I bet that dateTime is missing for this event.

Comment: Why don't you use a debugger! Believe me, sometimes using the debugger of your IDE is much better than asking questions on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Just because the `i`th element of an array exists, it does not mean that the element is not `null`.

Referencing a property or method of such an element will yield a `NullPointerException`.

If `i` went beyond the bounds of the array, you would get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` instead.

Check indexed array  elements for `null` before using them.

Sorry to be brief and not reference your code or other sources.  I am on my phone.  The likely source of your problem is pretty clear, though.